# Which windows-7 technologies will be installed on Vista when IE9 replaces IE8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

In one of the keynotes of the Microsoft PDC 2010 or 2011, Top-manager Ballmer, or Sinofsky , or someone else, said that IE9 was so important to Microsoft that they will put a lot of effort into the IE9 release. They were thinking about "forcing" users with IE8, i.e. Vista users, to upgrade to IE9.

He also said that "selected Windows 7 technologies" will be bundled with the IE9 installation (so you cannot install IE9 and IE8 side-by-side). I wonder which technologies these are? Is IE9 a substantial upgrade, or kind of a "hidden" service pack for Vista?

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything to fantastic, Vista is the black sheep no one talks about. If you really want to see, load Vista into a virtual machine and install IE9, at this point IE9 is listed as an important upgrade for Vista and 7, since Win 8 comes w/ IE 10..... Vista is unlikely to get more updates down the line.

Comment: @MDMoore313 I like Vista, with all service packs and  windows-updates installed it is now good enough for me and home use. It was bad/or immature when it came out. UserAccountControl was new, kept popping up for no apparent reason. Very annoying. But these days Vista runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get DirectX 11, Direct2D, Windows Imaging Component Improvements and Windows Ribbon component.

MSFT created a document about all improvements:

**About Platform Update for Windows Vista (Windows)**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can also get [Powershell 2.0 back to Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) if you want it (but this is not related to IE9).

Comment: Thanks. According to [Tim Mintner's Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tmintner/archive/2006/07/07/440729.aspx), a Powerhshell one-liner to check if Platform Update for Vista is installed is  `$wu = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Searcher";$totalupdates = $wu.GetTotalHistoryCount(); $wu.QueryHistory(0,$totalupdates) | where { $_.Title -match "Plat" } | select Title, Date`